# What are the necessary requirements for self nomination and where is the nomination link?

Tags: support, election, nominations

I want to know the criteria(requirements) to participate in the moderator election on SO. I know 4 badges, covention, deputy, Civic Duty, Strunk & White are required. Is there any certain amount of reputation required for that? Where can I access the link(given that I've fullfilled all the requirements), to nominate myself? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: You need a reputation greater than 3000.

Comment: I would also suggest that (even if you had the reputation) that a name like 'Downvoter' doesn't really show the true spirit of SO. That's like naming yourself PHPSucks or something. There is nothing *wrong* with calling yourself that, but it wouldn't get you off to the best start.

Comment: I'm guessing this must be a secondary account since you definitely don't meet the requirements on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 3,000 reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

Additionally, you must have the following badges:

- Civic Duty
- Strunk & White
- Deputy
- Convention

Once you meet the minimum requirements, you can nominate yourself by visiting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/election/) page, scrolling to the bottom and clicking on the `nominate yourself as a candidate` link. You can go and visit it now, but the system won't let you submit it until you meet all the requirements.

Comment: @Jaguar The link I posted appears to be broken. I'm working on figuring out the correct one. You should be able to visit it even if you don't fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @Jaguar I've updated the link to go to the election page, with instructions on what link to click there

Answer (score -1):

You need 3000 reputation on SO, 300 for elections on other sites. The link is on the election page if you qualify.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the complete information about 2013 Moderator Election

https://stackoverflow.com/election